# Calculating the line length between two points using oop java

Tags: java, oop

hi friends i need to Calculating the line length between two points using java oop method and get 3 line from 3 point then prove it is a Triangle and or not if it Triangle calculate the Triangle area
thank you

Comment: Seems like a homework problem.   WHat have you done so far ?

Comment: First you need to make class named point that have x and y coordinate. then you need to do some logic to calculate length and to prove it that three point is not in a line. so it must be triangle.

Answer (score 1):

For calculating line length, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance for the case of two dimensions

To get lines from points, make lines out of points `i % n` and `(i + 1) % n` where `n` is the number of points and `i` ranges from `0` to `n-1` like a standard for loop.

To prove three lines are a triangle - if you made them from three points, they obviously are. If they share only three points amongst them, they are a triangle as well (for instance you could add them to a `Set` and see if only three unique points exist).

EDIT: Daniel Robertus points out that they also need to not be colinear, even if you know their points are in common. One way to prove three lines aren't colinear is to compute the `tan2(y,x)` using `y2-y1` and `x2-x1`, which gives you the angle of that line - if they are colinear, then two of the lines will have the same angle. If they are not colinear, none of the lines will share an angle in common. (The proof of this is trivial.)

To calculate the area of a triangle, pick your favourite formula from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle

Comment: @Shanmuganathan Shanshayan Please try to code them and when you get stuck try to isolate the problem, solve the problem, google it and if you are 100% stuck then post your specific problem you are having.

Comment: I think you will be better served by general advice than code that is given to you (teach a man to fish).

Answer (score 0):

```
Point2D p1 = new Point2D.Double (10.0, 15.0);
Point2D p2 = new Point2D.Double (16.0, 7.0);
Point2D p3 = new Point2D.Double (12.0, 11.0);

System.out.println ("Distance from p1 to p2: " + p1.distance (p2));
System.out.println (
    "Area of {p1, p2, p3} triangle: " + 
    0.5 * p1.distance (p2) * new Line2D.Double (p1, p2).ptLineDist (p3));
```

Comment: @jahroy I thought stackoverflow is a site where people answer each other's questions, not learning each other.